# What is the difference between sorbet and sherbet

Tags: dessert, sorbet

From my [limited] exposure, it *seems* like `sorbet` is merely `sherbet` with a higher price tag.

Is that a fair understanding?

If not, what is a better way of understanding the difference(s)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, they are not quite the same.  [Sorbet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorbet) is ice sweetened with fruit, wine, or liquer.  [Italian ice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_ice), which is similar, does not contain ice but contains frozen fruit purees or similar.  [Sherbert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherbet) contains a small amount of dairy, but the milkfat content is less than 3%, differentiating it from ice cream.

In the U. S. what is commonly called sorbet is most likely an Italian ice.  The difference is the lower milk fat content.

Comment: cool - and that's the difference I couldn't find elsewhere :)

Comment: In my experience, the definition of sorbet vs. Italian ice is exactly reversed: sorbet is frozen fruit puree, and Italian ice is, like the name suggests, ice with flavoring syrup (different from a slushy in that the flavoring is added prior to freezing, instead of after).

Comment: My experience is more in line with Marti's.  For instance, Ciao Bella makes an incredible coconut sorbet which was clearly not ice with flavoring.

Comment: Apparently, my usage of *sorbet* is an Americanism. (At least per Wikipedia.) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorbet http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_ice Note that in all definitions, a *sorbet* contains no dairy whatsoever.

Comment: The words are used rather widely depending on where you are, so definitions are tricky without restricting to a locality.  This applies to food words in general.

Answer (score 6):

When I was a child in Britain, sherbet was a fizzy powder. Sorbet is definitely water, sugar and flavourings: no milk.

Comment: +1 Sherbet as the fizzy powder is a very British use of the word, especially if you tell people there should be a liquorice stick in it. ;-)